# Why does SQL Server trigger for INSERT actually updates unspecifed columns?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

A SQL Server database table has following 4 columns:

```
CreatedBy
UpdatedBy
CreateDatetime
UpdateDatetime
```

I created a trigger for updating `CreatedBy & CreateDatetime` columns after `INSERT`.

Here is the code of this trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestDb_create_time]
ON [dbo].[trgn]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE TestDb 
    SET CreateDatetime = GETDATE(), CreatedBy = USER_NAME()
    FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.TestDbID = TestDb.TestDbID
END
```

When the trigger runs after insert,  besides updating the `CreatedBy` & `CreateDatetime` columns, it also updated `UpdatedBy` and `UpdateDatetime`. The last 2 columns are not included in the trigger.

Why does the trigger also update them? What can I do to prevent the trigger from updating unspecified columns?

Adding more details to this question:

The SQL Server table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDb]
(
    [TestDbID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Item1] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Item2] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CreateDatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdateDatetime] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestDb] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestDbID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

SQL Server trigger for `INSERT`:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestDb_create_time]
ON [dbo].[TestDb]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE TestDb 
    SET CreateDatetime = GETDATE(), CreatedBy = USER_NAME()
    FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.TestDbID = TestDb.TestDbID
END

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDb] ENABLE TRIGGER [TestDb_create_time]
```

To test the trigger, I executed 2 SQL statements with 2 different user accounts:

```
INSERT INTO TestDb (item1) 
VALUES ('new record1')    --- connected with Windows account

INSERT INTO TestDb (item1) 
VALUES ('record2') --- connected with SQL user account
```

After the inserts, the data in the `TestDb` shows that the `UpdateDatetime` columns has value in 2 newly inserted records. The `UpdateDatetime` column is not included in the trigger.

Why did the trigger update that column?

[image: Data in test DB table:]

Comment: Do you have an after update trigger as well?

Comment: Update will not affect column not specified, if it does then that's a bug. Struggling to make sense of your code, you are updating *TestDb* but your table name is *trgn*, this doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: @David Browne:  Sorry for the error in the trigger code. It was not the actual trigger code.  It was modified from my test code and missed one thing in it.  I do plan to add update trigger.  I am still wondering why the INSERT trigger update the data columns that are not in the trigger?  If a table has 10 columns, how does the INSERT trigger decide which ones to update and which do not?

Comment: That trigger will only update two columns.  Add to your question the table the complete DDL for the table and trigger that reproduces this behavior.  You'll probably find the issue on  your own, but if you don't someone else may.

Comment: @David Browne:  I updated the question by adding details, include: db table structure, trigger code, test results and the question.  Could you let me know what I did wrong in the trigger?

Comment: Look for another trigger on the table in addition to your one

Comment: Drop your current table and then use the script you posted to re-create the table completely. Then run your insert statements - again, exactly as posted - and review the contents of that table.

Comment: @SMor:  I took the steps of drop and recreate the table, setup trigger and execute INSERT statements.  This time, the "UpdateDatetime" field was not updated.  What was the cause of the previous problem I observed?  I have seen that symptom in all my DB tables.  It made me worry.